# ngrx store selector returning undefined property

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-store

To get persistent user information across components I'm trying to implement NgRx store into my solution but have come stuck with getting the data from the store using selectors.

The error that comes back through the console is that user (part of the AuthState) is undefined but when logging in I pass it to the store and can see it when expanding source multiple times.

I've been following the documentation https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngrx-store-localstorage but am now a bit stuck, any suggestions on how to proceed or debug this effectively would be welcome.

Component

this.store.dispatch(addUser({ data: userDetails }));

Action

```
export const addUser = createAction(
  '[Auth] Add user',
  props<{ data: LoggedUserDetails }>()
);

export const loadUser = createAction(
  '[Auth] Load user'
);
```

Reducer

```
export const initialAuthState: AuthState = {
  user: {
    email: '',
    accessToken: '',
    idToken: '',
    name: '',
    id: ''
  },
  authenticated: false
};

// handles the retrieval of the user details
export const authReducer = createReducer(
  initialAuthState,
  on(addUser, (state, { data }) => ({
    ...state,
    user: data,
    authenticated: true
  })),
  on(loadUser, (state) => ({
    ...state,
    user: state.user,
    authenticated: state.authenticated
  }))
);
```

Selector

```
export const selectAuthState = (state: AppState) => state.authState;

export const selectUserDetails = createSelector(
  selectAuthState,
  (authState: AuthState) => authState.user);
```

Module

```
export function localStorageSyncReducer(
  reducer: ActionReducer<any>
): ActionReducer<any> {
  return localStorageSync({ keys: ['auth'], rehydrate: true })(reducer);
}

const metaReducers: Array<MetaReducer<any, any>> = [localStorageSyncReducer];

// within the imports rather than copying the entire module
StoreModule.forRoot(
  authReducer, { metaReducers }
)
```

shared component

```
this.store.pipe(select(selectUserDetails)).subscribe((res: LoggedUserDetails) => {
  // accessing from a shared component this gives the user is undefined error
  this.userDetails = res;
});
```

Comment: so initially you see `undefined`, but after you log in, the selector returns data or keeps delivering `undefined`?

Comment: What does loadUser do..?

Comment: Keeps delivering undefined and loadUser is intended to be used to bring back the user details from the store.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Selectors fire on *every* state change. Consequently I would guess your selector fires before the user state is initialized - it will fire again when you set the user state.

You can prevent the error by using the `?.` operator:

```
export const selectUserDetails = createSelector(
  selectAuthState,
  (authState: AuthState) => authState?.user;
```

Also your `on` in the reducer for `loadUser` sets the state to the same values it already had, so is redundant.

Comment: Thanks, that was definitely an issue and thank you for pointing out onLoad issue.

What I didn't realise was that I needed to have an appReducer and not just an authReducer (obvious now!) so there was never a state.